# How to conditionally shade a datetime span

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to shade the background of my plot for regions where one column values are negative. Is there a way to do this using axvspan by setting conditions?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2014-10-04","2014-10-05", "2014-10-06", "2014-10-07", 
                    "2014-10-08", "2014-10-09","2014-10-10"],
                   'values': [0.6, 0.3, 0.1,0.2,0.6,0.3, 0.4],'temp': [4,0,-1,-3,2,-3, -2]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)

            values  temp
date                    
2014-10-04     0.6     4
2014-10-05     0.3     0
2014-10-06     0.1    -1
2014-10-07     0.2    -3
2014-10-08     0.6     2
2014-10-09     0.3    -3
2014-10-10     0.4    -2
```

With a plot similar to this, but the shaded regions where the 'temp' column numbers are < 0. The real data is a very long time series and I cannot easily tell where xmin and xmax would begin and end.

```py
pl.plot(df['values'])
pl.axvspan("2014-10-04", "2014-10-05", color = 'lightblue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Plot the dataframe directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through all but the last row of the dataframe.

  - `idx` is the index name, which is the date of each observation, however, to easily get the next date, `i` for [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to provide the index location of the current date, and `i+1` will be the next date.
  - For example, if `i == 3` then `idx == 2014-10-07`, and `df.index[i+1] == 2014-10-08`.

```py
# plot the dataframe
ax = df.plot(y='values', figsize=(9, 6), legend=False)

# iterate through each row of the dataframe, don't include the last row
for i, (idx, (_, t)) in enumerate(df.iloc[:-1, :].iterrows()):
    # if the temp is negative
    if t < 0:
        # draw a span from the negative date to the next date
        ax.axvspan(idx, df.index[i+1], color='lightblue')
```

[image]